# How is it possible that I'm able to use plasma when I only installed lubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, lubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I just installed lubuntu dual boot with windows 10, it runs smoothly on my low end laptop. I'm confused though, when I turn on the computer, I get 2 choices Ubuntu (not lubuntu) or windows. And when I choose Ubuntu, and the login screen is displayed I get to choose either lubuntu or plasma. What's confusing me is that I just realized that KDE plasma is a desktop environment for kubuntu.  Since it's very customizable I'm sticking with it over lubuntu. I just want know is plasma installed automatically with lubuntu installation? Or did it just install kubuntu. (apologies for the noob question here I'm just getting started with Linux and so far it's better than ram hole windows10)

this is the output

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
neofetch is already the newest version (7.0.0-1).
neofetch set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Can you run the command `sudo apt install neofetch`, and post the output of `neofetch` by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1374041/edit) the question?

Comment: Well .... It does not come by default , maybe there is a bug that installed it .... Or maybe you have installed it yourself .... If you have installed lubuntu then it should show lubuntu instead of ubuntu ... So more or less it is a bug or you did something wrong :)

Comment: Plasma can be installed on any Linux distribution , So it doesn't mean that Plasma can only be used in Lubuntu , It is possible to install plasma in any Linux distribution with this command `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Also it doesn't seem to be any issue Just enjoy kde plasma :)

Comment: Also please [edit] the question and tell that how you installed lubuntu

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi sure bro hope I did that correctly I edited the description

Comment: @Algnis I downloaded the lastest 20.04, installed using a USB, I used the replace method when I was asked to choose a partition, and chose the free space. didn't knowhow to resize during installation so now I have 200 GB for lubuntu and 300 for windows10. that's it

Comment: No the thing Archisman Panigrahi asked you have done that wrong , You need to post the screenshot of `neofetch` command

Comment: Clarification, post (copy-paste) the output of the commadn `neofetch`. Please don't post a screenshot

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi If he/she will copy paste the output of neofetch then it would be ruined because of image of the ubuntu logo and stuff ,(The op of the question don't know how to code format)

Comment: @Algnis If OP does not post it in he code format, it is only a matter of adding three ticks to format it into code. Any of us can edit to do that.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Ya I know but still Neofetch will look best in image , But we all have different tastes so yeah

Comment: @Algnis I tried posting a screenshot but it didn't upload for some reason. Thanks but I'm switching to kubuntu

Answer (score 1):

KDE Plasma is **not** installed with a Lubuntu install.  KDE Plasma uses the identical Qt5 as Lubuntu's LXQt uses, however KDE Plasma also requires KF5 which Lubuntu does not come with (*though parts (some libraries) of it are included as some programs, eg. KDE Partition Manager, require it*).

To have the Kubuntu/Plasma option - you'll have caused it to be installed due to a *depends* rule as a consequence of something you've installed or by your install method.

What is included with Lubuntu can be found at

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-desktop

and what's found on the 20.04.3 ISO is

- https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/20.04/release/lubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest

You mentioned using the "*replace method*" of installation, and whilst I don't know what you mean by that exactly; a "*[Install using existing partition](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743)*" (*a Lubuntu Quality Assurance checklist install type*) will cause all *manually installed* packages that existed on the system prior to install, to be re-installed after your *fresh* Lubuntu is installed.

ie. if you added `kubuntu-desktop` to your system prior to the install of Lubuntu (*and Lubuntu was installed using any option that didn't format you `/` partition*), then those *manually installed* or *added* packages that existed in the old install, will be re-installed (*using internet if available*) after your new Lubuntu system is installed (*from your installation media*).

In my linked Lubuntu checklist *testcase* I used the example of including `clementine` as an example as it's a music player I like (*and **not** included by default with Lubuntu installs*), but it applies to any packages on the system **if** available in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: If you want to avoid this type of install; you can either **format** the partition **OR** not have internet connected; so it cannot download & install your previously *manually installed* packages.

Comment: Please also note my reference to `kubuntu-desktop` is example only ..   KDE Plasma can be offered in many ways by Kubuntu/KDE packages pre-existing on the system that you replaced with Lubuntu if those packages were marked as *manually installed*, or a *depends* rule caused them to be re-installed because of a *manually installed* package you had installed.  I used `kubuntu-desktop` as a example package, but it could be many others...

Comment: "Replace method" automatically chooses the free space partition for you during installation I'm installing Kubuntu now and after installing both Ubuntu and lubuntu, lubuntu is the only one that has this method apparently thanks for your answer but I have decided to finally switch to Kubuntu as lubuntu looked too basic for me, I know that's the point of it but I didn't like it and started using plasma environment instead of lubuntu

Comment: This install method isn't unique to Lubuntu; Lubuntu's name for it "*Install using existing partition*" is the only thing unique (*a term created by Walter/wxl in 19.04 cycle I think if not before in 18.10*) but I usually call it *Upgrade via re-install* with non-Lubuntu (*including Kubuntu*). It's been around for decade+ & likely much longer.  Only Lubuntu have a QA *testcase* for it; but I regularly QA-test in Xubuntu & others using it too.  @TravisFubu

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it answers your question; otherwise if it doesn't; you can wait for other answers that better suit.